# use custom font in android with css

Tags: android

i try to add some custom font to android application with css but font not change :
my code :

```
<style>
@font-face { 
font-family: 'fontname'; 
src: url('SOMEFONTURL.TTF');
}

body {
font-family: 'fontname';
color: red;
}
</style>
```

i,m sure SOMEFONTURL.TTF is exist.
also i try to read font in assets but not work :
my code :

```
<style>
@font-face { 
font-family: 'fontname'; 
src: url('file:///android_asset/font/font.TTF');
}

body {
font-family: 'fontname';
color: red;
}
</style>
```

(( Android 4.0.3 API Level 15))

Comment: So this is for a webview? If you open up your HTML in a normal browser on your computer, is it styled correctly?

Comment: yes for webview . i test this code in firefox +30 and chrome , work perfect..